# Websharper project in Visual Studio sometimes doesn't get updated in browser

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, f#, websharper

Take my apologies if the question is dumb.

I'm working on my Websharper project using 3 different computers. Sometimes when I pull a new code to any machine and hit 'build and run' (Ctrl+F5) my browser would display an old code instead of new one. 'Clean' and 'rebuild' don't help.

What's going on?

Comment: something in the browser cache?

Comment: @s952163 clearing browser cache, cookies didn't help (Chrome)

Comment: Ctrl+F5 in the browser works for me.

Comment: @cadull thanks for the suggestion, will definitely try the next time when it'll be reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Ctrl+F5' in the browser solved the problem, thanks to [@cadull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009927/cadull)